# How Do I Get My Focus Ability

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Pretty newbish question I'm sure but my mage is 10 almost 11 and I still don't have a focus ability like I see mentioned on here and in other places. How do I get it/unlock it?

Answer (score 4):

This is unlocked during the main story, if you haven't unlocked it yet at level 10 you probably should do some main quests. The game opens up a lot after a certain point, and you also get your specializations and focus ability around the same time.

Comment: To add to this, the quest (**PLOT SPOILERS AT THIS LINK**) "[In Your Heart Shall Burn](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/In_Your_Heart_Shall_Burn)", which you start at the War Table once you've picked a side, is the quest that you need to do to trigger the Herald getting their focus ability.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I'm one of those anal retentive have to clear Hinterlands guy before I move on. Actually up to the "In Your Heart Shall Burn" mission now so must be just around the corner. Looks like it's going to be getting much easier for me to finally kill the Hinterlands dragon.